Zeros of $\Gamma’$.
I’ve seen in many places (e.g here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2971) the following claims about the zeros of $\Gamma’$, without proof.
(1) It has only real zeros.
(2) The zeros are simple.
(3) Only one positive zero, infinitely many negative zeros.
I’ve searched for proofs of these claims, but did not find them. I’ve managed to prove (2),(3), essentially using the following formula —
Let $\psi:=\frac{\Gamma’}{\Gamma}$, then $\psi’(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(z+k\right)^{2}}$.
However, I don’t know how to rule out non-real zeros. If anyone has any idea how to prove this (i.e prove (1)), I would be very happy for references\advice. Thank you!

Might be easier to look up articles on the zeroes of the digamma function (which are the same as the zeroes of $\Gamma'$), as here

The gamma function has no zeros, therefore the zeros of its derivative are exactly the zeros of its logarithmic derivative, the digamma function, which has the series representation
$$
 \psi (z)=-\gamma +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right) \, .
$$
Now consider the imaginary part:
$$
 \operatorname{Im} \psi (z) = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{Im}\left( \frac{1}{n+z}\right)
=  \operatorname{Im} z \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|n+z|^2}
$$
and that is not zero if $\operatorname{Im} z \ne 0$. This proves that all zeros of $\psi$ (and therefore all zeros of $\Gamma'$) are real.

Fantastic! Thank you!
